# Sort table with Format-Table in Powershell

Tags: powershell

With the following code, I am able to get VM name with its IP address. I would like to know if it is possible to sort (ascending) the rows based on the IP column? I expect to see a sorted list of IPv4.

```
Get-VM | Get-VMGuest | Format-Table VM, IPAddress
```

Output is

```
VM                           IPAddress                             
--                           ---------                             
N1                           {10.1.1.32, fe80::51b:9698:4853:2ee5} 
N2                           {10.1.1.18, fe80::b640:8c2a:837c:613e}
```

Comment: To add on to what `harrymc` gave you. The practice is to select/filter left, format right. Thus formatting is normally the very last thing you'd do with collected data, passing the collected data to the Format-* cmdlet. The table format is the default for 4 or fewer properties. Example: `Get-VM | Where-Object Name -Like 'WS*' | Select-Object -Property Name, Status, State | Sort-Object -Property State`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
Get-VM | Get-VMGuest | Sort -Property IPAddress | Format-Table VM, IPAddress
```